# Usage of non UTF-8-encoded string as map key

Tags: arrays, string, dictionary, go

I would like to use a bytearray of variable length as key within a map.

```
myMap := make(map[[]byte]int)
```

As slices and variable length bytearrays are no valid key type in go, the code above is not valid.

Then I read that strings are just a set of 8-bit bytes, conventinally but **not necessarily** representing UTF-8-encoded text.

Are there any problems to use such a non UTF-8-encoded string for a map key regarding hashing?

The following code demonstrates how I converted *[]byte* to *string* and back to *[]byte* again:

```
package main

import (
"bytes"
"fmt"
)

func main() {

// src is a byte array with all available byte values
src := make([]byte, 256)
for i := 0; i < len(src); i++ {
    src[i] = byte(i)
}
fmt.Println("src:", src)

// convert byte array to string for key usage within a map
mapKey := string(src[:]) // <- can this be used for key in map[string]int?
//fmt.Println(mapKey) // <- this destroys the print function!
fmt.Printf("len(mapKey): %d\n", len(mapKey)) // <- that actually works

// convert string back to dst for binary usage
dst := []byte(mapKey)
fmt.Println("dst:", dst)

if bytes.Compare(src, dst) != 0 {
    panic("Ups... something went wrong!")
}
}
```

Comment: "Are there any problems to use such a non UTF-8-encoded string for a map key regarding hashing?" have you tried trying it? If so, did you encounter any issues?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem using `string` as key in a map where the string is not valid UTF-8.

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go:](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

> In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes.

And [Spec: Comparison operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

> String values are comparable and ordered, lexically byte-wise.

What matters is what bytes the `string` has, may it be valid or non-valid UTF-8 sequence. If 2 `string` values have the same invalid UTF-8 byte sequence, they are equal, and if not, they aren't.

Testing invalid and valid sequences (`"\xff"` and `"\x00"`):

```
m := map[string]byte{}
m["\xff"] = 1
m["\x00"] = 2
fmt.Println(m["\xff"], m["\x00"])
```

Output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DENLp9B688N)):

```
1 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your precise and fast answer :)